# Show Adview on Google custom tab

Tags: android, ads, chrome-custom-tabs

I am using Google Custom Tab in application to show external content.

Is there any way we can show Adview on top of the opened content in the tab?

Answer (score 1):

Although a Custom Tab shares the same task stack as the host application, it belongs to a different process: the browser. That means that the host application doesn't have access to the View hierarchy and will not be able to add an AdView on top of the Custom Tab activity.

Custom Tab allows a developer to [add a custom, 56dp high RemoteView to the bottom.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.java#L450-L471) It's the same RemoteViews used to create [AppWidgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) and follows the same limitations, so adding an AddView inside it probably won't be possible.